# Tail-recursive programming in Java

Tags: java, c++, performance, algorithm, recursion

I've been coding in C/C++ for a few years, and I just started Java recently. In one of the projects I've done, I was doing tail-recursion on a big data set (I apologize for not providing the code because I can't find it...). I realized an obvious performance issue as opposed to that in C/C++. Then I read a few articles about why JVM does not support tail call optimization (yet?) and that Java programmers usually, if not always, use loops in place of tail-recursive calls.

As such, is tail-recursive programming semantically wrong in Java, or is it just a bad practice in general, regardless of the language used?

Is there any difference between the following two Java functions performance-wise and semant**nic-wise?

**non-recursive**

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) 
        result *= i;

    return result;
}
```

**recursive**

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;

    return factorial(n-1) * n;
}
```

Also, does it make any difference to change the recursive version to the following?

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;

    //below is changed
    int result = factorial(n-1) * n;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tail-call optimization is not guaranteed in C++, so it's non-portable to rely on it.

Comment: For some programming languages like *Prolog* and *Haskell* recursion is the only means to perform iterations. Evidently in such case, tail recursion is implemented, since otherwise one would easily run out of call stack.

Comment: I see, so even for c, loops are a better choice to perform iterations over recursions?

Comment: @ThomasHsieh It's a question of what the algorithm is most naturally suited to; rarely is the overhead from a recursive call significant.

Comment: Oh ok I see. It's rather unnatural for me to, for instance, write a factorial function with loops. That's exactly what drove me to this concern. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tail-recursive programming in Java is not strictly wrong, it's just inefficient and may easily lead to stack overflows.

Given that tail recursion optimization is not guaranteed in C++ (as pointed out in one of the comments), I'd avoid it general in Java, Javascript, C++ etc.